# What's the "MTC Мобильная Почта" update on my Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2, malware

What's the wierd looking update that's just turned up on my Samsung Galaxy phone?

"MTC Мобильная Почта" by "OJSC Mobile TeleSystems".

The review section has lots of one-star comments saying its malware etc, but I'd have thought actual malware would look more like something I'd want to install than something wierd in Russian.

Should I be worried? Is this malware or some perfectly normal component buried in the OS that's somehow found its way into public view? Should I install the update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some searching due to the other answer and found someone on XDA [claiming](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=24009922&postcount=5) that this is a Market/Play bug, and you're seeing it because the Market thinks one of your apps is actually that OJSC Mobile app.

Even better, I found [this just-published story on The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/2012/3/26/2904389/google-play-bug-russian-email-app-samsung-android-seven):

> Samsung has several pieces of software that it installs on it devices but that aren't in the Google Play store (for obvious reasons). However, every single Android app has an app name that identifies it on the Android system, in this case the "unique" name is **com.seven.Z7**, which identifies Samsung's email app. What appears to have happened is that Russian developer OJSC Mobile Telesystems gave that unique identifier to its "МТС Мобильная Почта" app, and so these Samsung devices were tricked into thinking it was an update to Samsung's email client. Since Google Play allows for automatic updating of all apps, it was installed on many devices.

I couldn't find the app in the Play Store anymore, so perhaps Google has taken it down to resolve this.

Below is the original version of this post, which would still be applicable in more normal circumstances.

---

If it's a system app for supporting Cyrillic text, which is what it sounds like, it could hardly be called malware.  Crapware, perhaps, if you don't need it.

If you don't need it, then no need to update (unless you want to be rid of the notification, though in that case I recommend rooting and removing the app).  No reason not to update either I'd say — you already have it on your device, so unless it's doing something nasty in the new version in particular then you've already been exposed to any dangers it may contain :P.  Of course, updating will require more space on your device unless you are rooted and can entirely replace the original version with the update (normally the system keeps all original versions of system apps).

Comment: I've copied the cyrillic name from your answer into my question text and title. Thanks.

Comment: "Мобильная Почта" means "Mobile Mail" in Russian.

Comment: These identifiers are supposed to be unique simply because the only ones allowed to use com.seven.Z7 would be the ones who could control Z7.seven.com in the DNS system. It's not immediately obvious to me that seven.com has any connection with either Samsung or some Russian “MTC” company, does anyone know which of these used the name correctly, if either? (Assuming this is not actually an update for what Samsung installed, that is.)

Answer (score 1):

This is DEFINITELY an ugly mixup, as shown in the update on Verge. Just a Russian app with the same system ID as Samsung's app... so no need for hysteria, not everything in Russian spells a nuclear threat ;).

Answer (score 0):

From what i've read on XDA-Developers, it seems to be a russian telefoon company who pushed a update wrongfully to all (or a big group of) Samsung S2 users. Since the update isnt made for phones made Cyrillic text, it could cause your phone to crash.

so dont install it unless your absolutely sure you need it.

Comment: Can you please link to the relevant information on XDA-Developers?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix...this is a piggy-back app attached via a file. Go to your phone files, view your files as "List and Details." You should now see the date/times each file was created. Delete ALL files two days before and after when you first noticed the MTC app requesting update. Reboot phone and it will be gone from your Market. I did this four days ago and so far no MTC app. I never choose auto update for any app due to this reason.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Answer (score -4):

Ive read a few things online this morning about the MTC app being malware or a virus, It doesn't show in your apps list however it was said that if it is a virus it might be piggy backing off something else installed on the phone, I had it come up on my phone but not sure how to remove it yet

Comment: Source please .